# How to ignore or skip null values of table when filtering in Django?

Tags: python, django, datatable, filtering, isnull

I want to ignore or skip a filter clause when the data of that clause is null in the DB, in my case sometimes the digital_exp_score variable is Null, but I need to filter by that variable, the normal filter would be like this:

```
review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)
offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
                is_personalized=True,
                digital_exp_score__gte=review.digital
)
```

But when digital_exp_score is Null it won't work, I want to ignore those cases and just pass that condition, How I do that?

I have tried with the When Clause:

```
offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
                is_personalized=True,
                When(digital_exp_score__isnull=False ,
                     then=(digital_exp_score__gte=review.digital)
                     ),
)
```

And

```
offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
                is_personalized=True,
                digital_exp_score__gte=When(
                    digital_exp_score__isnull=False,
                    then=review.digital
                ),
)
```

But neither works, I get syntax error, those methods are only for the value at the right of the condition? Is there any method for checking the values at the left of the condition (the DB values)?

Something like this would be ideal:

```
offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
                is_personalized=True,
                digital_exp_score__gte=review.digital if digital_exp_score is not None else pass
)
```

Comment: So if `digital_exp_score` is `NULL`, you do not want to check the `digital_exp_score`. If it is not null, you want to retain the object in the queryset?

Comment: Yes, exactly that, is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [**`Q`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) to encode a disjunction. The logical equivalence of *a → b* is *¬ a ∨ b*:

```
from django.db.models import Q

review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)

offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
    Q(digital_exp_score=None) |
    Q(digital_exp_score__gte=review.digital),
    is_personalized=True,
)
```

or we can simply filter out objects for which `digital_exp_score` is not less than review.digital`. Django will then automatically include` NULL` itself:

```
from django.db.models import Q

review = Review.objects.get(id=review_id)

offers = OfferGeneric.objects.filter(
    ~Q(digital_exp_score__lt=review.digital),
    is_personalized=True,
)
```

Here the tilde (`~`) is a *negation* of the condition.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly! 
And is a well done explanation, the invert query is very useful to know!
One last question, here in the filter the `|` is an OR right?, so each ',' comma is an AND? so I could put an `&` instead of the commas?

Comment: @OOSS: If you use `Q` objects, you can use `&`, if we use named parameters, like in the last one, than you can not use `&` (or `|`), since this is just how Python parses parameters. But internally `.filter(..)` will indeed create `Q` objects, do the `&` logic to coonstruct a single one, and then translate that `Q` object to parts of the SQL query it is constructing.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it

```
OfferGeneric.objects.exclude(digital_exp_score__isnull=true) \
                    .filter(is_personalized=Treu,digitial_score__gte=review.digital)
```

although i imagine it would have worked with your other query... as i dont think NULL would pass the greater than test ... maybe i am misunderstanding what you are trying to do

based on your comment the correct query is

```
from django.models import Q
OfferGeneric.objects.filter(Q(OfferGeneric.digital_score__gte=review.digital) | 
                            Q(OfferGeneric.digital_score__isnull=True)).all()
```

Comment: No, it won't work because it will exclude all offers that have digital_exp_score as Null, What I want is to get all offers that satisfy this condition digitial_exp_score__gte=review.digital, BUT when digital_exp_score is Null I want just to skip that filter, in that way I can get the offers that has that field in null too. So how I can do that?

Comment: Yeah It will work now like that, but why the `.all()` at the end?

Comment: you dont need it i guess... its just habit